# VBA Basic web query login object error

Tags: vba, excel

I copied code from a different Stackoverflow answer but it's not working for me. Im trying to loggin into a site and then run a macro. Run-time error 91 (object variable or with block variable not set)

'**this is where the code stops**

`.document.all.Item("user").Value = "username"`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://booneilpropertymax.governmaxa.com/propertymax/rover30.asp?sid=4E131F244E474C2CA87112FA94C83B44"
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .document.all.Item("user").Value = "username"
        .document.all.Item("pass").Value = "password"
        .document.forms(0).SUBMIT
    End With


    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://booneilpropertymax.governmaxa.com/propertymax/tab_land.asp?t_nm=land&l_cr=1&t_wc=|parcelid=03-23-480-003&sid=6ECB98B7DA8F46FCBB04F83F7E225CF4" _
        , Destination:=Range("$J$1"))
        '.CommandType = 0
        .Name = _
        "tab_land.asp?t_nm=land&l_cr=1&t_wc=|parcelid=03-23-480-003&sid=6ECB98B7DA8F46FCBB04F83F7E225CF4"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "13"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End
```

Comment: Is that really your user ID and password?

Comment: That was my username and pass. I just caught that to.

Comment: You might want to change it -- it will still be visible in the version history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements your trying to interact with are contained in a frame.  An alternative would be to use

https://www.governmax.com/propertymax/user_login.asp?site=login&form=loginform&formelement=0&sid=4B105BB10FBA474D89D3FF256C2D5976

as your url.  This is the login page.  On this webpage the following code will work

```
ie.document.getElementsByName("user")(0).Value = "abcde"
ie.document.getElementsByName("pass")(0).Value = "12345"
ie.document.getElementsByName("login")(0).Click
```

Added later

The frame, although not an iFrame, behaves like an iFrame.  It provides an url, that when navigated to, the user can control the various elements.  To capture this url use

new_url = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).src

Appended even later

So your code would look like this

```
URL_1 = "http://booneilpropertymax.governmaxa.com/propertymax/rover30.asp?sid=4E131F244E474C2CA87112FA94C83B44"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate URL_1
    Do Until .readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    new_url = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).src
    ie.navigate new_url

    Do Until .readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    ie.document.getElementsByName("user")(0).Value = "username"
    ie.document.getElementsByName("pass")(0).Value = "pass"
    ie.document.getElementsByName("GO")(0).Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    'can't check past here because I can't get in - I don't have a pw, etc

    ie.document.getElementsByName("parcelid")(0).Value = (Sheet1.Range("H" & 1))
    ie.document.getElementsByName("go")(0).Click
 End With
```

So a couple of points:

1) the line capturing new_url must appear after you are on the initial page

2) It appears that the name of the click button is "GO" on the page new_url takes you to

3) There are two urls you can use to get the job done,  You can use the url you used in your original question and that I used in the block of code directly above.  With this url the elements you want to manipulate are in a frame, so you must use the new_url approach.  OR, you can use the url I used at the very top of this answer and that you used in your answer.  With this url, the elements you want to work with are not in a frame so you can put your text directly into the webpage, there is no need to use the new_url approach, in fact there is no new_url on this webpage since there is no frame.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the ignorance. The suggested page takes me to another site and im still getting an object error. Why would it work earlier but not now. Is the url constantly changing?

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

new_url = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(0).src

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://www.governmax.com/propertymax/user_login.asp?site=login&form=loginform&formelement=0&sid=4B105BB10FBA474D89D3FF256C2D5976"

    Do Until .readystate = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop


    ie.navigate new_url

    ie.document.getElementsByName("user")(0).Value = "username"
    ie.document.getElementsByName("pass")(0).Value = "pass"
    ie.document.getElementsByName("login")(0).Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    ie.document.getElementsByName("parcelid")(0).Value = (Sheet1.Range("H" & 1))
    ie.document.getElementsByName("go")(0).Click



 End With
```

Comment: No problem, see what I've added to my original answer

Comment: I think the end of url (sid=72CE81A2B93B4FE9AB3ED8F36A798C8B) changes everyday. I got it to work again but I have to update the (sid) every time.